# Export a model from 3DS Max to Photoshop that retains materials, texture, light etc..?

Tags: 3d, photoshop, 3dsmax

I bought a .max model that has materials, textures, lighting. When I export it from Max to a .3DS or .OBJ, and then import that into Photoshop CC, all I see is a grey shape.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction how to export and retain those things I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you placed the textures in the same directory as your .obj file when importing? (Grey means no textures, no textures most likely means it cannot resolve \ find them).
When exporting .obj make sure you tick the 'export material' as well, it will create a .material file containing the translated materials.

Comment: Yup. That was indeed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can tag the reply as a correct answer so that I get my points. Also helps others that ccomes in here.

Comment: I don't see how to tag a reply. Is there a way? If not, just answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the textures in the same directory as your .obj file when importing the file, grey  3d model means that textures does not get applied. Also when exporting .obj make sure you tick the 'export material' as well, this will then create a .material file containing the translated materials.